# Where should I include a global fixture in a django project?

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I have this fixture , and I want to make it global , where should I put it in my django project

```
@pytest.fixture
def auth_client(user = None):
    if(user is None):
        user = User.objects.create()
    client = APIClient()
    client.login(username=user.username, password=user.password)
    return client
```

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, just create a conftest.py in the main directory and put in it the fixture.